# Installing module within code with pip and ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, installation, add-in, pip

I am creating an arcmap add-in which relies on a third party module, usaddress. I am using pip to install the usaddress module on the user's computer. When I run the add in however, it says that usaddress was successfully installed but then fails to import the usaddress module with "No module named usaddress". Once I close arcmap and all python scripts, it then imports the module for some computers. Other computers I have tested, it still doesn't install the module at all. But when I run the code independent of the add-in, it successfully installs the module. This is not ideal as I can't do it on every user's machine.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

See the relevant code below:

```
import pip
import arcpy
required_pkgs=["usaddress"]
installed_pkgs=[pkg.key for pkg in pip.get_installed_distributions()]
for package in required_pkgs:
    if package not in installed_pkgs:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Installing {0}..................".format(package))
        pip.main(['install',package])
        arcpy.AddMessage("Succcessfully installed {0}..................".format(package))
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Upgrading {0}..................".format(package))
        pip.main(['install',"--upgrade", package])
import usaddress
```

Comment: What happen when you try it without handling fails. Just "pip.main(['install',package])" .

Comment: It still fails when I just use pip.main(['install',package])

Comment: A complete stab in the dark here but I know one can reload() modules, could try that?

Comment: @Hornbydd I wouldn't be able to reload the usaddress module even before it's able to be imported. I am having issues with the import.

Comment: Is each computer using the same version of ArcGIS and Python?

Comment: Are you running ArcPro or background geoprocessing on these machines? If so, could you be accessing their pip install and hence, installing your packages in a different directory?

Comment: @JCB They are all using ArcMap 10.5.1 and python 2.7.12. There's no difference in behaviour whether background processing is on or off. Pip is installed with ArcGIS 10.5.1 so it should be in the same location for all the computers.